# How to border and center a navigation bar with the float property in it?

Tags: html, css, css-float, navigationbar

I've got this navigation bar form w3schools but i want it to be centered in the page (horizontally) and i want it to be fully bordered and i can't get it right. It probably has something to do with the float property. If i border the links then each link gets it's own border and if i border the list then there's an empty border and the links are below it. If i center the bar then nothing happens. I've tried replacing the float property with the `display: inline;` property but that seems to have problems with the `display: block;` property.

```
a:link, a:visited {display: block; width: 80px; background-color: #0066FF; text-decoration: none; font-family: calibri; font-size: 20px; color: #FFFFFF;}    
a:hover {background-color: #0088FF}    
li {float: left;}    
ul {list-style-type: none; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;}    

<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li>    
<li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>    
<li><a href="foto's.html">Foto's</a></li>    
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>    
</ul>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish, what have you tried, and what problems did you encounter? "How to make a navigation bar?" is not helpful.

Comment: Try to avoid w3schools website it is known that over half of their stuff is outdated. there are plenty of tutorials on this with a google search

Comment: My school uses that website as main source but I also use other sources. It's just for the example. I'm trying to get that bar but I want it to be centered and bordered. The float property is probably causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead `float`. Give your `ul` a fixed `width` and apply `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #0088FF
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav ul li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a>
    </li
    ><li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
    </li
    ><li><a href="foto's.html">Foto's</a>
    </li
    ><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm usually working with classes instead of id's. I'll try to convert it but in case i can't, could you give me an example with classes? Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: @HYBR1D - Sure, but there is just one `id`(`#nav`).

Answer (score 0):

Study the example below.

```css
#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: green;
  }

#nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block; /* Gets them to stay next to each other */
  margin: 0 30px 0 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  }

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  }

#nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 35px;
  
  }
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
  
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li>    
<li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>    
<li><a href="foto's.html">Foto's</a></li>    
 
</ul>
  
  </div><!-- End Nav Bar -->
```

**Note:** This is just a basic example. As you get to understand how it's done, you can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.nav-container li:first-child {
 border-left: medium solid;
}

.nav-container li {
 border-bottom: medium solid;
 border-top: medium solid;
}

.nav-container li:last-child {
 border-right: medium solid;
}
</css>

<ul class="nav-container">
<li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li>    
<li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>    
<li><a href="foto's.html">Foto's</a></li>    
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a border around the navigation, add a border to the parent tag: in this case, the ul tag. This places a border around the children tags of the parent tag.

It is not necessary to add the :link and :visited unless you want them to have different results.

Change the float to inline-block because this gives it space that affects the parent tag, where inline does not.

Use padding instead of width in case some words are longer than 80px.

To avoid space between inline-blocks, set the parent tag, in this case ul, font-size to 0. Or use  comments in between tags. I did both so it'd work in safari.

Use margin: 0 auto; to automatically align elements to the center of the parent tag: in this case, the body tag.

Use display: table to wrap the ul tag to fit (wrap around) to its content.

Combine css rules into shorthand when possible: e.g. font-family and font-size to font: (size) (family).

```css
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: #0066FF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 20px calibri;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #0088FF;
}    

li {
    display: inline-block;
}    

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    border: 3px solid #00aaFF;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="foto's.html">Foto's</a></li><!--
            --><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>    
        </ul>
```